API Authorization in C#
Faced with a problem, developing an API integration, however the token I need to make a request expires every 30 minutes. Initially I thought about doing this dynamically, generating a token whenever the API runs, thus avoiding running the API with expired token. The problem is that when generating the token I always get a 403 Forbidden error. I've already replicated the code in Python and it works, but in C# I can't make it work at all. The funny thing is that I can't replicate this error in Insomnia, I can already guarantee that the credentials and URL are completely correct, as I used them in Python and worked, it just doesn't work in C#, does anyone have a solution?
private async Task<string> PostAccessToken(string apiKey, string secretKey)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestData requestData = new RequestData
                {
                    ApiKey = apiKey,
                    SecretKey = secretKey
                };

                // Criar um HttpClientHandler personalizado
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true; // Permitir redirecionamento automático
                handler.UseProxy = true; // Usar um proxy, se necessário
                                         // Outras configurações do handler, como certificados SSL, autenticação, etc.

                // Criar um HttpClient com o handler personalizado
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    // Adicionar o cabeçalho "App-Token"
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("App-Token", _wapstoreKey);

                    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
                    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{_BaseUrl}/auth", content);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Erro na requisição HTTP: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ocorreu um erro: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }

Ja tentei de tudo, nada funciona.

You should not new up an HttpClient instance. Use a static or singleton HttpClient, which you inject via DI.
Apart from that. Can you specify what "does not work" means? Any concrete errors?

As a troubleshooting step, intercept the traffic (e.g. using Fiddler) and compare a known-good request to a request that fails with 403. The solution should present itself very quickly.
